# PowerShell will append data even duplicates. How can I get it to only add unique data based on a date within the source data?

Tags: powershell

This code works as expected but it will append the .csv file every time it's ran regardless of the date contained in the source data. How can I get it to only append if the data is not a duplicate?

I've included a screenshot of the output file "myFilteredReport" for reference because I want it to check the TRADEDATE column as sometimes the code can be ran in the morning and contain data from two days ago and then ran again in the afternoon and pull data from yesterday. It just depends on when the website refreshed their data, out of my control.

```
powershell.exe wget https://www.cmegroup.com/ftp/pub/settle/nymex_future.csv -outfile "Y:\Test\nymex_futures_$(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd).csv"


# Import file with latest timestamp:
cd Y:\Test
$futuresFile = gci *.csv | sort lastWriteTime | select -last 1
$futures = import-csv $futuresFile


# Parses .csv file for product codes in text file. Modify product codes as needed.
$myLookups = gc .\NGL_lookup.txt
"lookups loaded: $($mylookups.count)"
$myFUTURES = @()
foreach($lookup in $myLookups){
"processing lookup $lookup..."
$myfutures += $futures |?{$_."product symbol" -like "$lookup"}
}

"Futures found: $($myfutures.count)"

# Remove -Append to overwrite existing data if preferred over append.
$myfutures | export-csv -Append Y:\Test\myFilteredReport.csv -NoTypeInformation


pause
```

[image]

Comment: You can't get it to skip duplicates if you never read in the existing file.

Comment: you MUST read the two data  sets before you can  filter them for uniqueness. [*grin*] ///// you may find  it easier to merge the new data with the older set ... and then filter out the unwanted items. it aint terribly _efficient_ ... but it is fairly clear.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to check your destination report before exporting, similar to the lookup you're already doing. You could add these steps to your existing foreach loop to keep from processing `$myfutures` twice:

```
# get the existing data
$FilteredReport = Import-Csv 'Y:\Test\myFilteredReport.csv'

$newFutures = $myfutures | Where {
  $Row = $_

  # check the whole filteredReport for duplicates
  if ( -Not ( $FilteredReport | 
    Where {
      $_.PRODUCT   -EQ $Row.PRODUCT -AND
      $_.TRADEDATE -EQ $Row.TRADEDATE  # I guessed on the field names 
    } 

  # If no duplicates, all good
  )) { return $true }
}

# export your de-duped data:
$newFutures | Export-CSV -Append 'Y:\Test\myFilteredReport.csv'
```

My personal preference is to use `Compare-Object`. Remember to remove the property it adds or you'll get another column, and use `-PassThru` to keep the whole object:

```sh
# Compare properties from both lists. Excludes duplicates by default:
$NewFutures = Compare $filteredReport $myfutures -Property PRODUCT,TRADEDATE -PassThru |
  Where { $_.SideIndicator -eq '=>' } |
  Select * -ExcludeProperty SideIndicator  # clean up the SideIndicator field

# export your de-duped data:
$newFutures | Export-CSV -Append 'Y:\Test\myFilteredReport.csv'
```